# converting java code to mips

Tags: java, mips, sieve-of-eratosthenes

This bit of Java code represents the sieve of eratosthenes method to finding prime numbers.

```
int n = 10;

// initially assume all integers are prime
boolean[] isPrime = new boolean[n + 1];
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    isPrime[i] = true;
}

// mark non-primes <= N using Sieve of Eratosthenes
for (int i = 2; i*i <= n; i++) {

    // if i is prime, then mark multiples of i as nonprime
    // suffices to consider mutiples i, i+1, ..., N/i
    if (isPrime[i]) {
        for (int j = i; i*j <= n; j++) {
            isPrime[i*j] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to convert it to MIPS.  Here is my code so far...

```
    .data

array:  .word   0:1000000   # array of 0s where 0 = "prime", 1 = "not prime"

    .globl main
main:
    addi $t0, $t0, 2          # i = 2

outerLoop:
    ble $s0, 10, Exit        # if (i x i <= array.length)
    mult $s0, $t0, $t0     # $s0 = i x i
    addi $t0, $t0, 1          # i++

    sll $t1, $t0, 2       # i x 4
    add $t1, $a0, $t1      # &array[i]
    lw $t1, 0($t1)        # array[i]
    bne $t1, $0, Exit         # if array[i] is prime

innerLoop:
    ble $s1, 10, Exit        # if (i x j <= array.length)
    move $t0, $t2             # j = i
    mult $s1, $t0, $t2     # $s1 = i x j    
                            # array[i x j]
   j outerLoop 

Exit: ...

    .text
```

I think I figured out how to access isPrime[i] correctly but I got stuck in the inner loop and couldn't figure out how to access the address isPrime[i*j].  I'd appreciate any help or corrections so far.

Comment: you're missing jump back to `innerLoop:` after accessing array[i*j]. and where is your `s2` initialized ?

Comment: fixed to be $s1 not $s2

Comment: `a0` too. so what's your question? you already used `lw` instruction for accessing array element i, given that your `a0` points to array base. just use `s1` instead of `t1` this time

Comment: do I have to change the offset again?

Comment: assuming your i*j is in `s1`, just issue these: `mult $s1, $s1, 4`, then `add $s1, $s1, $a0` then `lw <some register>, 0($s1)`